# What is this property of surjective continuous maps called?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a continuous map between topological spaces, which you can assume to be Hausdorff if you like.  Say that $f$ has property $P$ if for every compact subset $L\subseteq Y$, there exists a compact subset $K\subseteq X$ with $f(K)=L$.  Is there a more standard name for this?

Clearly a map with property $P$ must be surjective.  Any proper surjective map has property $P$.  A product projection $Y\times Z\to Y$ has property $P$ iff $Z\neq\emptyset$, but is only proper if $Z$ is compact.  More generally, I think that any surjective fibre bundle projection has property $P$.  Any map that has a continuous section has property $P$.

Comment: In the context of continuous linear operators between topological vector spaces one often says the $f$ *lifts compact sets* (similarly, $f$ may lift bounded sets, null sequences, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map $f\colon X\to Y$ is a *compact-covering* map if every compact $K\subseteq Y$ is the image of some compact $C\subseteq X$.

Comment: Do you have a **reference** for this definition?

Comment: Encyclopedia of General Topology - Authors: K.P. Hart, Jun-iti Nagata, J.E. Vaughan-1st Edition - October 1, 2003 - p. $ {\bf  c-03-5}$.